# Want to visually represent raw information

Tags: c#

I have a task to represent data in the form of tiles. Here is an example data:

```
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWDWWWWW
WCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCGGGGGGW
DCCCCCCCCCCCCCCSSdGGGGW
WCCCCCCCCCCCCCCSSSdddGW
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWDWWWWW
WCCCCCCCCCCWCCCCCCCCCCW
WCCCCCCCCCCWCCCCCCCCCCW
DCCCCCCCCCCWCCCCCCCCCCW
WCCCCCCCCCCWCCCCCCCCCCW
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
```

Legend:

- W = wall
- D = Door
- C = Carpet
- S = Sand
- d = Dirt
- G = Grass

I'm trying to represent this in an application. If I take a grid of such data, say 300x300, and decide on a fixed size that represents an object, the resulting map will be massive and require quite a lot of scrolling.

Putting aside the later requirements of painting painting blocks of object and what not, I mainly trying to get a smooth fast scrolling and basic editing on each object. I'm a WinForm developer and don't know if it'll be a good idea to do this in WinForm. WPF comes to mind as it's more like a free roam application instead of the rigid WinForms.

Any suggestions please.

Comment: Panel, Double Buffering, OnPaint, OnClick

Comment: Yes, trying that right now... hangs if grid goes above 100x100

Comment: Look at SDL. http://www.libsdl.org/

Comment: I'd be more inclined to use something like OpenTK to represent something like this.

Comment: Offtopic - just checked on OpenTK because of your comment, @Magus. Seems interesting!

Comment: I followed up on OpenTK as well, which led me to Duality: http://www.fetzenet.de/blog/?page_id=697

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a 80s-inspired look, You may want to look into isometric projection, Hassan. It works very nicely with 2D-mapped information.

Basically, you define graphic content following a faux-isometric perspective grid, where the content may represent floor tiles, such as these:

[image]

You may then parse your data maps into surface tiles, which may even represent structures (walls, in your case):

[image]

This is an example of a fully-implemented isometric (2.5D) room projection:

[image]
<sub>(source: [pixelcurse.com](http://pixelcurse.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/The_White_Room_by_gness_18.png))</sub>

You may want to use an isometric engine in order to help you with data visualization (there's quite a few of them), or build your own. Some resources follows:

- You can find an [XNA tutorial here](http://xnaresources.com/default.asp?page=TUTORIALS) that'll introduce to isometric manipulation.
- ice2d game engine
- StackOverflow posts:

  - [Drawing Isometric Tilemaps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4515264/drawing-isometric-tilemaps)
  - [Drawing Isometric game worlds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/892811/drawing-isometric-game-worlds?rq=1)

Comment: While this might be slightly overkill, it does look nice, and I've always been a fan of this style. His data may be too simple to handle the directional component, in which case he should probably just do regular square tiles.

Comment: Data is simple + the there is no `y` axis. I love this though. There is the occasional part where there is a carpet under the door

Comment: Actually, there's no extra axis as well on that representation, @HassanGulzar - it only looks that way because the tile itself may have a 'height' parameter associated to it (floor: 0px tall, wall: 100px tall, for example). And Carpeted Door may have a different symbol (say, [P]); you just need to proper interpret and render it.

Comment: You're correct, @Magus, but I must confess I picked that sample image because it was a very neat way to represent the 2.5D concept. ;)

Comment: Another possibility would be a layered concept. Particularly in a game constrained to a grid, you might have a boolean pathing map which determines which objects are passable. For a more complicated example like above, you might go for a three layer approach, with a pathing, terrain, and object layer, which would make open/closed states for doors easier. Ultimately it's a matter of determining the goal, however.

Comment: Still trying to figure out what works best. The tile-map I'm trying to  represent is one from RimWorld. I'm construction from the save file. I've a lot of time and code in following the XNA path. But for Visual Studio 2013, there was indirect support plus it invokes GFX. I'm looking for a winform way to do it and at worst case, WPF